# calling functions without objects or passing values

Tags: java, oop, user-defined-functions

I want to call a user defined function inside a function without creating an object or passing any value to the called function. Is there any possible way to do that? consider the following code

```
 import java.io.*;
 public class sorting
{
int number[]=new int[5];
void input()throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        number[i]=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    }
}

void sort()
{
    int no;
    for(int i=0;i<5-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(number[j]<number[i])
            {
                no=number[i];
                number[i]=number[j];
                number[j]=no;
            }
        }
    }
}

void display()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(number[i]+"\t");
    }
}

public static void main()throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    sorting o1=new sorting();

    o1.input();
    o1.sort();
    o1.display();
}
```

}

this is a code for sequential sort. in void main i've created an object o1 and called the methods. but instead of calling 3 methods i want my job to be done by calling just one of them. by my knowledge that can be done by calling a function inside another function.

Comment: Think what you need is a `static` method

Comment: It is not clear what you are really looking for, but I guess you can use class function which does not need any object creation at all, but I do not know what you mean passing any value? do you have any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The code below is an example that fulfills your conditions:

```
//static -> no object creation
public static void a() {
    b(); //call function inside a function
}

//static -> no object creation
//no arguments -> you do not pass any value to your function
public static void b() {
    System.out.println("output something");
}
```

This answers your question. If it does not help you, please rephrase your question so that it is more clear what your question is.